# How to copy the value of a cell in a hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have three columns: **Longitude Latitude Link**

I want to create a link in every row using the value of longitude and latitude.
Example: For longitude 2.254299319 and latitude 48.83910264 i want to insert

```
HYPERLINK("https://www.google.fr/maps/@48.83910264,2.3492276,14z")
```

in the column link.
Is it possible to do so without any script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B<>"", 
 "https://www.google.fr/maps/@"&B1:B&","&A1:A&"z", ))
```

[image: 0]